# How do I make children's props update when parent state changes for children initialized in a map function?

Tags: reactjs, state, map-function

I have a bunch of child components being initialized in a map function in ComponentDidMount:

```
this.mappedApplications = this.props.applications.map((application, key) =>
            <ApplicationCard
                selectedYear={this.state.openApplicationYear}
                applicationYear={application.application_year}
                handleArrowClick={this.handleApplicationCardArrowClick}
                key={key}
            />, this
        );

        this.setState({
            applications: this.mappedApplications,
        });
```

When the state.openApplicationYear changes I want it to change for all of the Application Cards. I do a check in the application card show info if the selected year matches the application year, with the goal that only one card will be open at a time. The cards have dropdown arrows that allow the user to open or close them. Right now the parent's openApplicationYear is changing correctly, but the children's aren't updating.

Here is the render function if it helps:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="dashboard__card">
                <h3 className="mb-3">Applications</h3>
                {this.state.applications}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I have bound "this" to the map function as seen above. Is there anything else I need to do to update the children when the parent's state changes?

Comment: Don't store components in state like this, they need to be created in the render as a part of the component lifecycle. Map over a set of data `this.props.applications` in the render and render the elements, this should fix your issue.

Comment: @JohnRuddell that worked perfectly, thanks!